# How to subtract key out of Json api response and check if there are more keys, and if so put them in a list?

Tags: python, json, list, api, response

So I have a complex problem, I have a JSON API response with the key: 'key' in 'persons'

but in some cases there is more than 1 'key', I tried to make a for loop to go through the response but it will print it like 20 times. Also, I have no idea to put those 'keys' in a list or a place where I can access them.

to make it a bit easier i have the response that i get out of my .request

```
{'id': 'a2b1109e-e142-4559-984c-3f9997b1db6a', 'externalId': None, 'name': 'tyr', 'description': '', 'client': '', 'reference': '56345', 'isMonitoring': False, 'monitoringSince': None, 'hasRiskProfile': True, 'riskProfile': 5, 'monitorFrequency': 4, 'mainBindable': None, 'organizationId': '65647b97-5ada-4362-bb3f-cae016722be6', 'userId': 'dd3cc015-e5cf-4a03-9408-74b102900836', 'createDate': '2021-03-23T11:29:55.2027037Z', 'updateDate': '2021-03-23T11:29:55.2027039Z', 'lastMonitorDate': '2021-03-23T11:29:55.2027039Z', 'persons': [{'firstname': 'ya', 'surname': 'o', 'dateOfBirth': '', 'updatedWithIdinIdentificationRequestPerson': None, 'relatedList': None, 'updatedWithIdinIdentificationRequestPersonDate': None, 'history': [], 'fullname': 'ya o', 'externalId': None, 'key': '8b92c210-eee6-4ab2-a093-48e4428af7f8', 'searchResults': [], 'requests': [], 'createDate': '2021-03-23T11:29:57.3853552Z', 'updateDate': '2021-03-23T11:29:57.3853553Z', 'archivedDate': None, 'isArchived': False, 'hasPepSearchResults': False, 'notes': []}], 'businesses': [], 'monitorIds': [], 'addresses': [], 'notifcations': [], 'monitors': []}
```

the number of keys can be different each time, so I will need to make a check to see if the key that gets back is already existing if so then do nothing, if the key is not existing then save that key in a variable.

here is a example of a response when there are 2 keys"key",

```
   {'id': '44b2203b-b2c8-41f0-8fde-b697ec02a8c8', 'externalId': None, 'name': 'tyr', 'description': '', 'client': '', 'reference': '56345', 'isMonitoring': False, 'monitoringSince': None, 'hasRiskProfile': True, 'riskProfile': 5, 'monitorFrequency': 4, 'mainBindable': None, 'organizationId': '65647b97-5ada-4362-bb3f-cae016722be6', 'userId': 'dd3cc015-e5cf-4a03-9408-74b102900836', 'createDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:53.0345703Z', 'updateDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:53.0345705Z', 'lastMonitorDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:53.0345706Z', 'persons': [{'firstname': 'marnox', 'surname': 'bolier', 'dateOfBirth': '', 'updatedWithIdinIdentificationRequestPerson': None, 'relatedList': None, 'updatedWithIdinIdentificationRequestPersonDate': None, 'history': [], 'fullname': 'marnox bolier', 'externalId': None, 'key': '68e4a9ad-2431-490f-a216-61a0cbd81c57', 'searchResults': [{'at': '2021-03-23T20:58:54.6796804Z', 'totalHits': 0, 'type': None, 'results': [{'paymentRequired': False, 'service': None, 'source': 'CIR', 'items': [], 'count': 0}, {'paymentRequired': False, 'service': 'VaV61', 'source': 'Entity', 'items': [], 'count': 0}], 'requestable': {'id': 'bf9dea30-2f4a-467a-a7b1-6765ceaee517', 'name': 'marnox bolier', 'createDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:55.5409494Z', 'updateDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:55.5409495Z', 'type': 'NotFoundPerson', 'sourceKey': 'A135D3C449EA15C66B6444611E2C97EC', 'picture': None, 'properties': {}, 'resultKey': None, 'data': None, 'archivedDate': None, 'isArchived': False}, 'cachedResult': False}], 'requests': [{'id': '57866866-85c4-43d8-8caa-b47a90b12be4', 'name': 'marnox bolier (TO UPDATE)', 'createDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:56.3090064Z', 'updateDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:56.3090064Z', 'type': 'NotFoundPerson', 'sourceKey': 'AB1AD3379D84D5D2404CF8326CDA054D', 'picture': None, 'properties': {}, 'resultKey': None, 'data': None, 'archivedDate': None, 'isArchived': False}], 'createDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:53.912784Z', 'updateDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:53.912784Z', 'archivedDate': None, 'isArchived': False, 'hasPepSearchResults': True, 'notes': []}, {'firstname': 'marnix', 'surname': 'bolier', 'dateOfBirth': '', 'updatedWithIdinIdentificationRequestPerson': None, 'relatedList': None, 'updatedWithIdinIdentificationRequestPersonDate': None, 'history': [], 'fullname': 'marnix bolier', 'externalId': None, 'key': 'c0475154-530e-4802-b215-1d26a2c7f208', 'searchResults': [], 'requests': [], 'createDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:56.9078002Z', 'updateDate': '2021-03-23T20:58:56.9078002Z', 'archivedDate': None, 'isArchived': False, 'hasPepSearchResults': False, 'notes': []}], 'businesses': [], 'monitorIds': [], 'addresses': [], 'notifcations': [], 'monitors': []}
```

update i solved my first problem getting more than 1 key with a for loop:

```
for persons in api_response['persons']:
        print(persons['key'])
```

output:

```
 0b8eb227-0105-40a3-bc8b-8e3ef345a3f3
 d9b68e7a-ffdd-44ea-86a4-ea4c541146b4
```

how can I only save the last result so in this case

```
d9b68e7a-ffdd-44ea-86a4-ea4c541146b4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `requests` to fetch the data from the api your response will simply have a `json()` function attached. Meaning you can do something like this:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("example.com/api/random/endpoint")
data = response.json()
```

The json function in turn does the equivalent of `json.loads()` with the content of the response. Assuming your API returns a JSON object this will be converted to a dictionary (in accordance with the [json conversion table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

After that you can follow go2nirvana's answer and manipulate this dictionary as you would any dict. For example using `data.pop("key")` to remove the value at that key, iterate over the dictionary, or whatever else you can do with a dictionary.

Admittedly your question is a bit vague and I am not sure exactly what you want to do with the data you recieve, but this is how you get that data in a form that is easy to work with within python.

Comment: please check my updated question, i provided my response, because when i use data.pop("key") it gives me a keyerror

Comment: @MarnixBolier in that case the key is most likely missing, you can give the pop function a default to return if the key is missing, for example `data.pop("key", None)` will return None if the key "key" is missing. `None` can be anything, such as False or a string etc.

Comment: you would think that, but please check the attached response. there is a key called key in the response...

Comment: @MarnixBolier There is no key called `key` on the data itself, that is on an object in the persons array. So you would have to access this. For example `data["persons"][0]["key"]`, whcih selects the persons array from the data, selects the first entry (an object) in that array, and then selects the key (called `key`) from that first object.

Comment: yes, I am already using that for the responses with just 1 key, but sometimes there is a double response, it will print the response above but right after that another response. the response basically shows all persons in the binder. I need a piece of code that extract all those keys and check if there is another key to add. but first step is making sure it can identify all keys in the whole response

Comment: i added my double key response to my question.

Comment: perfect i got the first part working: for persons in api_response['persons']:
            print(persons['key'])  this will now show me all keys but how can i save the last key it gives me? so the most recent key. for example i have key: 1234 and key 12345 how can i make it so it only saves 12345 ?

Comment: thanks for the help man i managed to solve the whole thing with your advice